# AJAX - JSON syntax error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I am working on a project for a client and they want to be able to update a list of costs dynamically depending on the registrants status as member/non-member or student. So I thought AJAX would have been the best way to do this but I am having trouble with my implementations. Every time I send my object I get a syntax error. I have placed the code below.

JavaScript

```
function checkMember(){
    var member = document.getElementById("user_mem_id");
    if(member.value == "" || member.value.trim() == ""){
        document.getElementById("testError").innerHTML = "Please enter a membership id<br>";
        document.getElementById("testError").style.color = "red";
    }else{
        var json = { "data":[{"membership_id":member.value}]}
        var xmlHttp = false;
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");// For Old Microsoft Browsers
        }catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");// For Microsoft IE 6.0+
            }catch (e2) {
                xmlHttp = false;// No Browser accepts the XMLHTTP Object then false
            }
        }

        if (!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();//For Mozilla, Opera Browsers
        }

        xmlHttp.open("POST","member_check.php",true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlHttp.send("data=" + json); 

        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200){
                    document.getElementById("testError").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
                    console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
                    json_last_error;
            };
        };
    }
}
```

PHP

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST["data"]))
    {
        $data = $_POST["data"];
        $res = json_decode($data, true);
        echo $data[membership_id];
    }
```

The other issue is that when I try and  access the membership "cell" of the data array I get illegal off set string. Thus I thought I had declared my original JSON object incorrectly but I appears (as I have viewed many examples on here and else where) that I have declared that correctly.

Comment: And the error is..? But to clarify, you're sending unescaped json through your request?  You do know only jquery or other libraries can do that, right?

Comment: - Syntax error, malformed JSON

Comment: You can't send unescaped, raw json through a simple request like that.  jQuery is able to because it actually transforms the data into a proper query string.

Comment: The problem with your array is that you try to access your json string instead of you decoded array. try $res["data"]["membership_id"]; instead.

Comment: it might be kinda cheating but jquery could save you some pain: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: I don't think that is true. I tried a simple string "test" and it still failed

Comment: @soccermanstan Last time I checked, "test" is not valid JSON.

Comment: @Daedalus I meant as a second variable to the JSON. To me the only variable that would have to be escaped is member.value. Thus I was trying to say when I replaced that with "test" (as in examples where they used {"name":"Darth Vader"}) I still got the - Syntax error, malformed JSON error.

Comment: btw, if you accept an answer (by clicking on the tick) you get points too :)

Comment: @soccermanstan You're still wrong; you're trying to convert an object to a string without any special rules applied.  See my answer for why that fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong with your code.  As I stated in my first comment to you, you need to escape your json before you send it in the query string, as json converted to a string, without any special rules applied turns into `[object Object]`, and that isn't valid json, nor is it parsed as such.

To do that, use [`JSON.stringify(json);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).  Example:

```
    function checkMember(){
    var member = document.getElementById("user_mem_id");
    if(member.value == "" || member.value.trim() == ""){
        document.getElementById("testError").innerHTML = "Please enter a membership id<br>";
        document.getElementById("testError").style.color = "red";
    }else{
        var json = { "data":[{"membership_id":member.value}]}
        var xmlHttp = false;
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");// For Old Microsoft Browsers
        }catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");// For Microsoft IE 6.0+
            }catch (e2) {
                xmlHttp = false;// No Browser accepts the XMLHTTP Object then false
            }
        }

        if (!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();//For Mozilla, Opera Browsers
        }

        xmlHttp.open("POST","member_check.php",true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlHttp.send("data=" + JSON.stringify(json));
        //json turned into proper string
        //I should also note, you should url-encode this string if it contains
        //any special characters using encodeURIComponent()

        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200){
                    document.getElementById("testError").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
                    console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
                    //json_last_error; //Commented this out, as it will
                    //echo an error, causing the script to halt, as it doesn't
                    //exist.
            };
        };
    }
}
```

Secondly, you send an object whose key 'data' contains an array of objects.. not a simple object:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["data"]))
{
    $data = $_POST["data"];
    $res = json_decode($data, true);
        echo $data[membership_id]; // There are many things wrong here
        //     ^       ^ this is not a constant and likely does not exist.
        //     |- This is still your string, which doesn't work
}
<?php

if(isset($_POST["data"]))
{
    $data = $_POST["data"];
    $res = json_decode($data, true);
        echo $res['data'][0]['membership_id'];
        //      ^   ^     ^      ^
        //      |   |first item  |-string
        //The result|-string
}
```

Hopefully my comments will be self explanatory.. but in case they are not...  $res is your decoded array, 'data' is the first position of that array, 0 is the first position of the array at that position, and 'membership_id' is the item you want to access.  You access members as strings, indexes as integers.

Comment: Thanks. So in summary I should basically stringfy JSON before sending to PHP, and once in PHP I should use the decoded variable? Any cases in which you would not want to stringfy the JSON

Comment: @soccermanstan Cases where you would not want to stringify json, would be using a javascript library like jQuery, which turns it into a query string anyway(unless specific options are set), or one is not using ajax, and needs to modify the object directly.  And yes; once in php, use the decoded variable.  Otherwise you're treating a string like an array of characters.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use stringify in order to perform the post successfully.

```
var json = { "data":[{"membership_id":member.value}]};
json_data = JSON.stringify(json);
```

then use json_data in your ajax call.

Comment: This wouldn't be turning it into json; its already json; it'd be turning it into a string.

Comment: sorry, yes you're quite right but doesn't he need to do that to post it?

Comment: I never said that he didn't.  In fact, I already said as much.  Also, there's a bit more wrong with the code than that.  I'm giving others the chance to correct that in an answer, but if it isn't in a bit(maybe 10 minutes), I'll post my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem with your code is the ";" terminator when you are defining variable. Check your following line

> json = { "data":[{"membership_id":member.value}]}

You haven't put a semicolon at the end. (however it might still work a few times but mostly its an error)

Rather you have written a lot of code too. I would suggest you to use jquery's [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function  to simplify your task.

Also in case if you only have membership id in your json data its more easy to create a json object like the one below

> var json = {"membership_id" :  member.value " } ;

Also you need to send your json data after quoting in string using `JSON.stringify(json)`

Comment: While semi-colons are required in js, this is not why it isn't parsing.